# Rails how to Use mail_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, contacts

I'm trying to use mail_form under Rails for a contact us form on a page.

But the instructions are rather confusing, does anyone know of a tutorial or how to use it?

Step by step pls. Thanks in advance!